# How to generate Gaussian's dot in specific range by numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

In mathematica people can do something like this (100 dots)

```
gdots = GaussianQuadratureWeights[100, 0, 2]
```

To generate 100 Gaussian nodes in the range of 0 to 2

But in numpy i can only generate it in range of -1 to 1

```
gdots = np.polynomial.legendre.leggauss(100)[0]
```

How can i generate Gaussian's dot in range of 0 to 2? I'm not sure may be the answer is just shift phase

Comment: Just adding 1 should work fine.

Comment: @Lev Levitsky Ok i think it work well thanks!